# Why doesn't Java String have static string manipulation methods?

Tags: java, api-design, null

Why didn't **Java designers** create static versions of string manipulation methods in the `java.lang.String` class? The following methods are what I refer to, but the question can be extended to other non-static methods in the class as well.

```
concat(String)                        substring(int, int)
replace(char, char)                   toLowerCase()
replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)   toLowerCase(Locale)
replaceAll(String, String)            toString()
replaceFirst(String, String)          toUpperCase()
split(String)                         toUpperCase(Locale)
split(String, int)                    trim()
substring(int)
```

Having only non-static versions of these methods forces **explicit** null-checking anywhere such a method has to be called. For example, simply calling `example = example.trim()` would lead to *NullPointerException* if `String example = null`. So the programmer has to do the following boilerplate null check:

```
if (example != null)
    example = example.trim();
// OR:
example = (example==null) ? null : example.trim();
example = (example==null) ? null : example.substring(5);
```

I would imagine it would have been a lot more convenient if `String` had static versions of these methods (perhaps even *exclusively*), which would take the input string as the first argument:

```
example = String.trim(example);
example = String.replace(example, 'a', 'b');
example = String.substring(example, 5);
```

This would have led to cleaner code written by programmers which would have automatically taken care of null cases by simply returning null, rather than forcing programmers to explicitly handle null cases. The *returning of null* makes sense to me since manipulating a *null* string should result in a *null* string, not an error.

**Why didn't** Java designers think of this when they designed the `String` class in Java 1 or Java 2, or even add such a functionality in a later Java version?

Comment: I would suggest replacing "Why didn't Java designers think of X" with "Why did Java designers decide against X". Give them the basic credit of not being blind to the option.

Comment: `null` is an exceptional state and should be handled explicitly.

Comment: If only Java had extension methods (like C#), you could eat the cake and have the cake :) Invoke methods as if they were instance methods, but protect against null exceptions

Comment: @KonradMorawski: Personally I find that a gross misuse of extension methods. If you have a null value then what on earth are you doing trying to call methods on it, you're just going to confuse everyone who reads that code. It's a poor reimplementation of a `Maybe<T>` type, I guess?

Comment: _If you have a null value then what on earth are you doing trying to call methods on it_ Erm, you do realize that a program can't predict in advance that a value is null, right? Examples are examples, used to convey a message - they are not to be taken as an exact representation of actual application.

Comment: @Phoshi one **has** to keep in mind that extension methods are NOT real methods, they're just syntax sugar. But I agree that it's controversial. I wish C# / Java offered some sort of built-in syntactic null-safety, like - say - Kotlin. `string name = employee?.personalData?.name`. Just as a shortcut for all these repetitive `if (employee != null)`s. Related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196031/evil-use-of-maybe-monad-and-extension-methods-in-c

Comment: @KonradMorawski: Correct, however they **look** like real methods. When reading the code without the knowledge they're extension methods it's gonna be really really confusing. Side note, that null safe dot operator is apparently an upcoming feature for C#, so you'll get your wish. Along with the null coalescing operator (??) it should make nulls much easier to work with, though personally I'd still prefer a first class Maybe type that's not gonna happen at this stage in the language's life.

Comment: @ADTC *Erm, you do realize that a program can't predict in advance that a value is null, right?* - You should define the contracts between your interfaces in a way that you *can* be sure if a value is allowed to be null or not. Null-checking everywhere means you have a program design issue.

Comment: related: [Best way to handle nulls in Java?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/51076/best-way-to-handle-nulls-in-java)

Comment: You are right, null safe version of java string library StringUtils is implemented by [apache commons project](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html), it tries to reduce boilerplate code needed when dealing with strings

Comment: @Phoshi: Some reference types (especially `String`) are generally used not to encapsulate the identify of an object, but to rather the value contained therein.  Just as it is useful to have fields of type `int` default to a value which can be used just like zero, so too it could be useful to have types that encapsulate data in references to immutable objects also have a "valid" default value.

Comment: @supercat: I'd argue that "0" is an equally poor sentinel for "no/invalid/not applicable", if not worse. 0 is even a valid integer--int op 0 will compile and run without error (except in the case of division)--whereas null at least has the courtesy to throw. Not every scenario requires that "default" value, and giving every scenario it has probably led to more bugs than any other design mistake.

Comment: @Phoshi: There are times when it is useful for a type to have a valid default value, and other times when it isn't.  I would posit that when there are times where it would be useful to have a type behave one way, and times when it would be useful for it to behave differently, allowing programmers to specify what they want (e.g. have integer types which wrap on overflow, and types which throw exceptions) is often be better than trying to formulate a single rule.

Comment: @supercat: I do not at all disagree with that, which makes me think I misunderstood your original point. Forcing behaviour (like a null-as-'default') is only going to lead to bugs.

Comment: @Phoshi: My point was that it would have been useful to have a type which behaved like a primitive with a valid default, *in addition to* a type which doesn't.  Though I guess since Java doesn't override `==` for classes, it should maybe have a primitive which behaves like string but with an invalid default (if a primitive string type existed, it would probably get used a lot by people wanting `==` to represent equality comparison, whether or not they wanted the default value to be a valid blank string)

Comment: @supercat: If I'm reading you right, that's what I suggest `Maybe t` for. For any given type T, which does not have an "invalid" state, you can enhance it with one by wrapping it in a `Maybe`.

Comment: The real shame is that Java *has* nullin the first place. https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2015/08/31/the-worst-mistake-of-computer-science/

Answer (score 30):

> The returning of null makes sense to me since manipulating a null string should result in a null string, not an error

Well, that is *your* opinion. Others may argument that String operations on a null object, which does not contain a String, make no sense and hence should throw an Exception

Why "Java designers" did or did not something is difficult to anwer.

There are already libraries out there which can do null-safe String operations, e.g. [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) of Apache Commons. You can use that or similar libraries if you need them.

---

**Addition based on your comments**

Reading through the comments, it seems like the real problem you face is that you have to check for `null` all over your code. That can be an indicator of a bad program design without clearly defined contracts between interfaces. You might want to read [Avoiding “!= null” statements in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/271874/1328300)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I guess the real question is, why do we have to depend on an external library or home-brewed classes when such a basic feature can be made part of standard Java?

Comment: @ADTC let's put the question the other way round: Why should "Java designers" include something into the language, if there are already lots of good libraries out there, well tested and documented? How to define a "basic feature" is opinion based. Doesn't mostly every project need some external library for "Basic functionality" (unit testing, mocking, date and time,...)? It ain't a big deal, is it?

Comment: One way of dealing with nulls is using Guava's `Optional` - https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained

Answer (score 10):

IMO the whole "if arg is null return null"  approach to writing methods needlessly increases the cyclomatic complexity of your program.

Early Java libs used the return null approach,  but the JDK guys always guarded against null with exceptions.

With time,  I think the latter approach has come out as the clear winner.

Why?  Since null fields break a lot of oo principles. You simply cannot treat them as members of a polymorphic class. This means that  you always have to code special cases for null,  and hence your cyclomatic complexity soars when you have to assume that things can be null.

In order to solve your problems,  consider using the null object pattern instead of relying on null fields.

Comment: But `String` is not polymorphic, no? And how do you use the null object pattern for an already existing type like String?

Comment: String is not polymorphic,  no.  But even so you would like to know that you can call instance methods on any string reference that you have. This works for all non-null references. String already has a null object: the empty string.  Just like lists have the empty list.  So ask yourself why the empty string isn't enough in your case.  I guess that you use a null string to flag some special case.  Ask yourself if you can use a separate flag for that special case.

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling: A field of type `int` defaults to zero rather than `null`.  Conceptually it should be possible to have a `string` type whose default value would be an empty string rather than `null` [such a type could semantically be to `String` what `int` is to `Integer`].  The fact that a non-empty `string` would internally hold a reference to a heap object would be an implementation detail; there's no reason it couldn't behave semantically like a primitive.

Comment: @supercat: Agreed.  I think it would have been better to forbid null values for refefences unless explicitly enabled.  Default non-null and final fields.  Many types already have null behaviour objects

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling: Having storage locations of all types default to all-bytes-zero, and providing that structure types can be assigned via all-bytes-copy, greatly simplifies a framework, but pretty much implies that types with *mutable* reference semantics must default to null.  It would have been helpful, however, to have had framework support for value types which would encapsulate a single reference *and would "box" as--and could unbox from--that reference type*.

Answer (score 3):

Not saying this is the reason, but except for toString, all of these methods are easily encapsulated in a static helper class, while the reverse is not true.

I.e. if you want Stings.toUpper(string input) the code for that is easy to write,  but if you want instance.toUpper and all you have is String.toUpper, well, that is impossible...unless they introduce extension methods, which most likely wasn't even considered at the time.

Comment: Good point, although more of a comment than an answer. But even given that, why do we have to depend on an external library or home-brewed classes when such a basic feature can be made part of standard Java?

Comment: As of now, you do have `String.format` (static), but you can't do `"something %s".format(id)`.

Comment: @adtc: because it's not a basic feature of the language to do it via a static class. Starting from that premise, there's a lot of reasons not to do so - unnecessary code/code bloat, duplicate functionality, cost of development/maintenance.

Answer (score -2):

In java, that string is an object. That's a design choice.

Object references can be null and are null if there is no object assigned to it. If you call such an object, a NullPointerException is thrown.
That's standard oo-behaviour.

Java designers made the choice of having strings as object and having those methods throwing null-pointer exceptions is what you get if you want strings to be objects.

> Why didn't Java designers think of this when they designed the String class in Java 1 or Java 2, or even add such a functionality in a later Java version?

They probably did think about it and chose to incorporate oo-behaviour.

Comment: May I know, how is creating static methods to take care of null cases _not OO behavior_? To be clear, I'm not saying it is, but I'm trying to understand why you say the design decision is to incorporate OO behavior.

Comment: Static methods are more like functions. And for the use you want they shouldn't even be part of the string class rather be part of some utility class. Just like math class functions.

Comment: Just because strings are objects doesn't mean that the String class can't have static methods. And indeed it has some already, eg. `String.format`. (Same in C#, by the way). So if that's a design choice, it can't come solely from the fact that strings are objects, and it's not applied consistently.

Comment: @PieterB I wouldn't complain if at least such methods were provided in a `Strings` utility class, like we have `Arrays` utility class (_although I understand it was created out of sheer necessity due to arrays being some sort of a weird cross between primitives and objects :)_).. as long as it was part of standard Java and didn't require dependencies.